How can I increase the maximum number of images for a single request with GPT4o on Azure?
I use gpt-4o-2024-05-13 via Azure. By default, the current maximum number of images for a single request is 20, since I get that error otherwise:
Error code: 400 - {'error': {'code': 'BadRequest', 
'message': 'Too many images in request. Max is 20.', 'param': None, 'type': None}}

How can I increase the maximum number of images for a single request with GPT4o on Azure?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/openai/quotas-limits mentions a "GPT-4o max images per request (# of images in the messages array/conversation history)", and they don't say it is a default value, so I infer from it that the max value cannot it be raised:



Limit Name
Limit Value




OpenAI resources per region per Azure subscription
30


Default DALL-E 2 quota limits
2 concurrent requests


Default DALL-E 3 quota limits
2 capacity units (6 requests per minute)


Default Whisper quota limits
3 requests per minute


Maximum prompt tokens per request
Varies per model. For more information, see Azure OpenAI Service models


Max fine-tuned model deployments
5


Total number of training jobs per resource
100


Max simultaneous running training jobs per resource
1


Max training jobs queued
20


Max Files per resource (fine-tuning)
50


Total size of all files per resource (fine-tuning)
1 GB


Max training job time (job will fail if exceeded)
720 hours


Max training job size (tokens in training file) x (# of epochs)
2 Billion


Max size of all files per upload (Azure OpenAI on your data)
16 MB


Max number or inputs in array with /embeddings
2048


Max number of /chat/completions messages
2048


Max number of /chat/completions functions
128


Max number of /chat completions tools
128


Maximum number of Provisioned throughput units per deployment
100,000


Max files per Assistant/thread
20


Max file size for Assistants & fine-tuning
512 MB


Assistants token limit
2,000,000 token limit


GPT-4o max images per request (# of images in the messages array/conversation history)
10


GPT-4 vision-preview & GPT-4 turbo-2024-04-09 default max tokens
16Increase the max_tokens parameter value to avoid truncated responses. GPT-4o max tokens defaults to 4096.



Note that the documentation incorrectly states that GPT-4o max images per request (# of images in the messages array/conversation history) is 10, whereas the actual max when calling the API is 20.
